# How to switch the repackager off?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

If you use the Spring Boot Gradle plugin you can use the [`enabled` configuration property](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration) to switch the repackager off.

But it seems the Spring Boot Maven plugin hasn't that configuration property.

Are there any way to switch the repackager off in Spring Boot Maven plugin?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`skip` property](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html) that you can use

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can also use a placeholder to only skip in a profile or using another condition.